# Rtools is required to build R packages

Tags: r, rtools

How install Rtools?
I want to create a R package but I get the following message: WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/

What is it the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The message tells you everything you need to know. Just download RTools for your installed version of R (I assume you need to install the latest version, which would be RTools35).

During the installation process make sure you check the box where it asks you if you would like to add RTools to the system path.